# Sonatype Nexus proxy for CRAN packages?

Tags: r, nexus, cran, sonatype

Our organization uses Sonatype Nexus to manage artifacts, whether they're internally-hosted stuff we've developed, or proxies to other repositories like Apache or similar.  Most stuff is JAR-based.

My group does most of its work in R, and we're wondering whether it makes sense to 1) deploy our internal code as R packages in Nexus, and 2) create a proxy to a CRAN mirror in Nexus.  I guess this would take some glue code, but I'm not very cozy with Nexus, so I'm not really sure what that would look like.  Ideally it would let us install R packages by hitting Nexus directly, rather than downloading first & manually installing afterwards.

Anyone have suggestions or precedent?

Comment: Nexus will host any type of file. Problem is the proxy functionality is restricted to a small number of repository formats (Maven, NuGet, etc). Do you know the format of the CRAN repository? (I'm not familiar with it)

Comment: It seems to be its own custom "format".  Its artifacts are `*.tar.gz` or `*.zip` files, there's a directory structure, and an index file saying what's available in the repository.

Comment: Yes, most repositories would have these features. Problem is compatibility...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since NXRM 3.20.0 support for CRAN is offered in the default install thanks to Sonatype adopting the below mentioned community plugin.

For older NXRM release the Nexus Community has a [plugin](http://exchange.sonatype.com/details?extension=5135491292) that adds support for CRAN repositories. You can find it on [GitHub](https://github.com/sonatype-nexus-community/nexus-repository-r) to install yourself.

Comment: Yes - we started using that plugin about a year ago and it's working quite well for us.

Answer (score 1):

Nexus now natively supports R packages as of version 3.20

Check out the release notes: https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/formats/r-repositories#RRepositories-RRepositoryGroups

I was able to create R repo's with the same automation.

Answer (score 0):

How about placing your internal zipped package on an (internal only, if you like) URL that you can then point the [devtools](https://github.com/hadley/devtools)::[install_url](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/blob/master/R/install-url.r) function to?

Comment: That works, it's basically what we do now (with the addition of running the `write_PACKAGES()` function to make the directory a valid CRAN-like site), but it doesn't help the development group have all their dependencies in Nexus.  Using Nexus/Maven does have advantages, like describing all dependencies explicitly in one place, no matter what type of artifacts they are.